# How to send byteArray from android to wcf through ksoap2

Tags: c#, android, wcf

Actually I can send integer or string but I don't know how to send byte Array.

Here is my wcf code. It receive byte Array then return string.

```
 public string GetFirstName(byte[] bmpArray)
    {
        //Bitmap bitmap = ImageTypeConverter.ArrayToImage(source, 480, 640);
        //bitmap.Save(Environment.CurrentDirectory + "test" + ".bmp", System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Bmp);

        return "ImageSaveComplete";
    }
```

This is part of android code.

```
SoapObject request =  new SoapObject(NAMESPACE,   METHOD_NAME);


      SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope =  new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);

      new MarshalBase64().register(envelope);
      envelope.encodingStyle=SoapEnvelope.ENC;
      request.addProperty("source", bmpArray);      
      envelope.dotNet =   true;
      envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);
      HttpTransportSE androidHttpTransport =  new HttpTransportSE(URL);
```

Actually It is wrong code.

Somebody help me to solve this problem.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you can edit the service you could make the service take a string instead of bytes and send through a base64 encoded string. But you can send bytes this is how my code looks, but it seems the same as yours

```
SoapObject request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, METHOD_NAME);
request.addProperty("source", bmpArray);
SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);
new MarshalBase64().register(envelope);
envelope.dotNet = true;
envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);
HttpTransportSE androidHttpTransport = new HttpTransportSE(URL, 300000);
```